# How to insert data from one table to another in a loop considering performance?

Tags: sql-server, insert, bulkinsert, database-performance

I need to insert data from one table to another in a loop with 10k rows in each loop run.

I want to try this because my `insert into ***() select () from ###` takes so much time as source table is having some millions of records.

Will there be any improvement in performance by using this approach?

Comment: Have you considered indexing? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Are you trying to make a copy of the table? Does the destination table have the same indexes, constraints, etc.? What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Chucky I doubt that indexes are the problem - after all the OP is reading the entire table (millions of rows). Also this is a SQL Server question - why link to MySQL documentation?

Comment: at which time this insertion happens .. my question while you copying the data is your source table locked if so then it will have a big effect on performance ..

Answer (score 4):

You can try inserting in batches and see if there is any performance improvement. Here is the sample code:

```
DECLARE @Count INT
DECLARE @Start INT

SET @Start = 1
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM TableName1

WHILE @Start<=@Count
BEGIN
    WITH cte
    AS
    (
        SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) AS 'RowNum' FROM TableName1
    )

    INSERT INTO TableName2 SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM cte WHERE RowNum >= @Start AND RowNum < @Start+10000

    SET @Start += 10000

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'
END
```

Here 10000 is the batch size and you can change this value as per your convenience.

Comment: This will be an overhead .. it will slow the process

Comment: Hi, what should I do in case I have no means of getting '@count'? This is a very useful code snippet

Comment: And why would be that? @count is nothing but the total number of records in the table which you are trying to query.